# bootstrap make-xx-column() mixins are not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

So, I've boiled this down to just the bare minimum.  As nearly as I can tell, some bootstrap mixins are just not working.  Specifically  .make-md-column() and .make-sm-column() flat don't seem to do anything.

At first, I thought it was WebEssentials not compiling the .less file correctly, so I kicked over to just using less.js and compiling on the client-side.  Still no love

So in the page below, the labels Span1 and Span2 appear in 2 columns at medium size and in 1 column on smaller views.

Based on my .less, I think taht spans 3 and 4 should be exactly the same (except green -- I added that just to be sure that something was coming through)  Spans 3 and 4 never go 2-column.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css"/>
<link href="Content/testless.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/less-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <!-- this row uses no LESS-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <span>Span1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <span>Span2</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="div-container">
            <span>Span3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="div-container">
            <span>Span4</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

and here's the less

```
    @import (reference) 'bootstrap/bootstrap.less';
//@import 'bootstrap/bootstrap.less';

.div-container {
    color: green;
    .make-md-column(6);
    .make-sm-column(12);
}
```

Comment: put "../" before the path

Comment: It's finding the files -- I confirmed that in the debugger.  I also added the color: green part to make sure that my .less file was doing something.

Answer (score 4):

### Smallest to Largest

The order of your `make-xx-column(X)` calls is important. Your code:

```
.div-container {
    color: green;
    .make-md-column(6);
    .make-sm-column(12);
}
```

Generates this CSS for the media queries:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .div-container {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .div-container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

In this order, the cascade of the CSS selectors is working against you, because the `768px` minimum is *after* the `992px`, so when you are at say `1000px`, *both* media query blocks apply since both are under that number, but the css cascade chooses the last one defined, which will always be `768px` (single column). [SEE EXAMPLE FIDDLE WITH THIS ORDER.](http://jsfiddle.net/K5KCT/3/) So you need this:

```
.div-container {
    color: green;
    .make-sm-column(12); /* reversed order */
    .make-md-column(6);
}
```

Generates this CSS for the media queries:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .div-container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .div-container {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Now, at `1000px` the `992px` applies, but if it drops below `992px`, then the `min-width` condition prevents that one from applying, and the `768px` takes over. [SEE EXAMPLE FIDDLE WITH THIS ORDER.](http://jsfiddle.net/K5KCT/2/)

**So the order of your `make-xx-column(X)` calls must be from smallest to largest.**

Comment: Can you believe that didn't work?  I read your post and thought "eureka!" (I'm a c# programmer, not an html guy -- didn't know any of that).  It works in the fiddle links, but when I bring those up, I see css, not the LESS.  Here's a gist of exactly what I'm doing: https://gist.github.com/jsmarsch/8721817  when I fixed up my .less file, it still didn't work (I changed the color of the spans from green to blue to make sure it wasn't a cache problem)

Comment: Yes, the fiddle was just demonstrating the effect. You should be getting something similar to my example in your compiled css from your LESS. What actual css output do you get for `.div-container`?